# Height in Javascript doesn't render as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So in javascript I am trying to make a section of my website to be 100% - "nav"

you can think of it like 2 visible objects only, the first really big, and the second is small on the bottom.

CSS declared like:

```
#mainHeader{
     height: 100vh;
}

#nav{
     height 90px;
}
```

and I have created this in javascript / jquery

this executes upon

```
 <body onload = "function()"> </body>

 var mainHeaderHeight = $("#mainHeader").outerHeight(true) - $("nav").outerHeight(true);
 $("#mainHeader").css("height",mainHeaderHeight + "px");
```

What it looks like: [image: Extra Webpage content peeks higher]
[image: What I want it to look like]

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save yourself the jQuery trouble and use the CSS3 option [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) (since you are using the quite "modern" `vh` anyway):

```
#mainHeader {
    height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}
```

Comment: This does work, except that I want to possibly later to change it automatically if I decide to change the 90px to something smaller or larger. Automatic is always good :D

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting a `nav` element instead of the `#nav` you need to match the `id` in your CSS.

```js
var mainHeaderHeight = $("#mainHeader").outerHeight(true) - $("#nav").outerHeight(true);
$("#mainHeader").css("height",mainHeaderHeight + "px");
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainHeader{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav{
  height 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainHeader">main</div>
<div id="nav">nav</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have exactly that, I thought it would be implied :D *{padding :0; margin: 0}